# How to print contact number as one by one without using looping and default conversion?

Tags: c

Example : My contact number is 9876543210. We will save this number as either as integer or longInt as we know. Actually i need to print my contact number as one by one without any conversion (Int -> String) and do not use looping.

Comment: You could use a recursive function that gets last digit and calls itself with the other digits. After returning from recursive calls, print the stored digit.

Comment: That is a problem for a recursive solution (the function calling itself takes the place of the loops) Fine here -- but be aware each recursive call is a separate function call that requires a separate function stack. If your repeated calls go too deep, you can easily exhaust your stack space.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In principle you're right, but not on this task. Even a `long long` has so few digits that there will be no stack overflow.

Comment: @thebusybee -- you misunderstood. In my comment I say the recursion is **"Fine here -- but..."**. I agree it is 100% okay for this issue.

Comment: Oh yes, we both said the same. :-}

Answer (score 1):

If you are still stuck on how to approach a recusive function, start with understanding that every recursive function has 2-parts:

1 A **Base-Case** which is the condition that is checked to determine when the recursion should end; and

2 A **Recursive Call** (meaning the function calls itself).

In your case of extracting the digits from a number, you simply want to extracts the first digit with `number % 10` which will isolate the least significant base-10 digit. Then you want to divide the number by `10` and repeat.

Where you would normally *repeat* by calling the modulo and division in a loop, here you want to make a separate function call passing the result of `number / 10` as the new parameter to your function.

You continue until your Base-Case is satisfied, and then the recursion begins to *unwind* where you return from the deepest function where you reach your Base-Case back into the previous function call -- and all the way back to the original. Careful placement of your outputting of the ASCII character for that digit will allow the numbers to be printed in-order.

A ***very minimal*** recursive function to do this could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void prnnum (int n)
{
    if (n == 0)                 /* base-case, when n==0, stop recursion */
        return;

    int digit = n % 10;         /* save digit to print */
    prnnum (n / 10);            /* make recursive call */
    putchar (digit + '0');      /* output ASCII value of digit on return */
}
```

(thinking though what may be needed to accommodate negative values, if anything, etc.. is left to you)

You can add a short `main()` that lets you pass in different numbers to test, e.g.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int n = 54321;

    if (argc > 1 && sscanf (argv[1], "%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;

    prnnum (n);
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Running without any command line input using the default value for `n = 54321;`, you receive:

```
$ ./bin/recursiveprnnum
54321
```

Passing in another number as the 1st argument you could do:

```
$ ./bin/recursiveprnnum 9378456
9378456
```

And in each case the digits have been printed one digit at a time and without a loop. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with using pointers but taking modulus of number by 10 is the easiest method but it has limitations. If you have + at the start of the number then this method will not work as it only deals with digit..So my method will work for both cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Function Prototype

void printNum(char *num);

int main(){

  // Creating a pointer, pointing
  // toward your number or anyother array
  char *num = "9876543210";

  // Calling printNum function to
  // print array word by word.
  printNum(num);

  return 0;
}

void printNum(char *num){
  /**********************************************
  This function takes a pointer to an array and
  call itself  again and again untill it founds
  null character
  ***********************************************/
  char *pnum;
  pnum = num;
  printf("%c\n", *pnum);  // print character on current address

  if(*pnum!='\0')         // This logic is used to avoid any loop
    printNum(++pnum);     //  increment 1 byte to address and call the funtion.
}
```

Comment: A bit of a problem with the Problem Description being *"We will save this number as either as integer or longInt"* -- but I agree with you it is better handled as a character string.

Comment: woops! you are right i carelessly read this question..my bad.. . Your method will apply for this question but mine is as alternative in case someone don't have these restrictions of int. Thank for correcting.

Comment: No biggie -- not like I've never done that before... `:)`